# Cloudfront Invalidation for custom origin root

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Anyone know how to invalidate the root document of a custom origin that use's friendly url's?

eg: `example.com` ?

What would be the correct Object Path to request via the AWS Create Invalidation dialog?

The documentation only refers to actual files eg: `images/image1.jpg`, and where it does mention folders there are never the root only `images/` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The leading slash is optional¹ in an invalidation request for anything other than the root, but for the root of the site, the path to invalidate should just be `/`.

¹ *optional* in the console only.  When interacting with the API (including with aws-cli and the SDKs) the leading slash is required.  It isn't clear why the console implicitly and invisibly adds a slash when one isn't supplied, but that's what is happenning.  Best practice would be to always supply the `/`.